# Play Framework - Parallel promises with partial acceptable failure

Tags: java, playframework, promise

I currently try to call a bunch of webservices in parallel. In the end I want to evaluate all the responses. Therefore I use `Promise.sequence`. Unfortunately the whole method fails if one of the web calls failed. I would be satisfied if I just get the response of the succeeded calls.

Is there some way to perform the `Promise.sequence` and just retrieve the succeeded calls? After that it would be nice to handle the failed calls in any separate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for now. For each `Promise` i create via `ws.url("http://...").get()` i define a `recover` method, e.g.

```
ws.url(theUrl).get().recover((t) -> null)
```

So when these Promises are processed via `Promise.sequence` no error is thrown (because it was already catched by the recover of the particular WS call promise).

Later on I just have to check if a result is null and then drop it from further processing.